# PolyHook x64Detour not hooking into Direct3DCreate9

Tags: c++, assembly

I'm having issues hooking into a process using polyhook. For some reason pDevice is never set.

```
#include "PolyHook.hpp"
#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN
#include "CatchUnitTest.h"
#include <d3d9.h>

/* this type is already defined in d3d9.h so i commented it out
typedef IDirect3D9* Direct3DCreate9(
    UINT SDKVersion
);*/
typedef IDirect3D9*(__stdcall* tDirect3DCreate9)(UINT SDKVersion);
tDirect3DCreate9* otDirect3DCreate9;

tDirect3DCreate9 oDirect3DCreate9;

LPDIRECT3D9 pDevice;

LPDIRECT3D9 __stdcall hkDirect3DCreate9(UINT SDKVersion)
{
    pDevice = oDirect3DCreate9(SDKVersion);
    return pDevice;
}

DWORD WINAPI inject()
{
    AllocConsole();
    freopen_s((FILE**)stdout, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
    std::cout << "SETUP" << std::endl;

    HMODULE d3d = GetModuleHandle("d3d9.dll");

    PLH::Detour* PLHDirect3DCreate9 = new PLH::Detour;
    std::cout << "new DETOUR" << std::endl;
    PLHDirect3DCreate9->SetupHook((BYTE*)GetProcAddress(d3d, "Direct3DCreate9"), (BYTE*)&hkDirect3DCreate9);
    std::cout << "setup HOOK" << std::endl;
    PLHDirect3DCreate9->Hook();
    oDirect3DCreate9 = PLHDirect3DCreate9->GetOriginal<tDirect3DCreate9>();
    while (!pDevice) {
        std::cout << "no pdevice" << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "END" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "pDevice: " << pDevice << std::endl;
    for (;;) {

    }
}
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD Reason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    if (Reason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
    {
        DisableThreadLibraryCalls(hModule);
        HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)inject, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        CloseHandle(hThread);
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

and my output:
[image]

I am doing something terribly wrong, but I'm not quite sure what. any guidance would be helpful. my end game is to get the LPDIRECT3D9 set by Direct3DCreate9

I am using this library off of github
https://github.com/stevemk14ebr/PolyHook

I've found some other posts about this issue online, but none mentioned their solution.

Comment: no any errors - look for [src code](https://github.com/stevemk14ebr/PolyHook/blob/master/PolyHook/PolyHook.hpp#L1166) - lib **always** post this warning

Comment: well thats upsetting.. @RbMm because my hkDirect3DCreate9 method is not being called though because pDevice is never set

Comment: i not understand in what your problem/question. the **warining** (not error) message library print (if enable print warnings) always when set x64 hook. will be this hook later called or not - does not matter here

Comment: @RbMm thanks to your guidance, iv'e updated my question.

Comment: @CodeofGod `Direct3DCreate9` doesn't return the device

Comment: make sure  `GetModuleHandle` gives correct address

Comment: it's possible that PolyHook just fails at it, I remember I had some issues with it too

Comment: you'd be better off using MS Detours or MinHook for traditional jmp hooks.

Comment: you can also try IAT/EAT hook since it's an export :)